# Jquery calendar with only 30 days active for picking others should be disabled

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, calendar

I need a suggestion to display a calendar from which an user can select only one day (simple).

But my requirement is to show only 30 days. i.e, if the user visits the page on 15/01/2015. He should be able to pick only one day between 15/01/2015 - 15/02/2015.

The days before 15/01/2015 and days after 15/02/2015 should be disabled for selection.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this mate.Hope this might help you.. :)

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            minDate:'0',
            maxDate: '+1m',
    });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L9k72a9b/)

**FYI**

[Datepicker API](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

[minDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate)

[maxDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate)